# how generate wcf proxy classes from many services in same namespace

Tags: wcf, service

I have two services that use same library business model. For generation
proxy classes I get two classes Service1.A and Service2.A, but A is one type of data. I want get one class. Is it possibly. How do it?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to call WCF service. **Proxy** and **Channel**.

In Proxy, you can add WCF service to your project with **Add Service Reference ...** In this way, proxy classes generated automatically. You can't use your shared classes. Because, shared classes generated again as proxy.

If you can use shared classes, you must choose **Channel** way. In channel, add reference ServiceContact (interface) and DataContract to the client project.

```
    var address = new EndpointAddress("..."); // Service address
    var binding = new BasicHttpBinding(); // Binding type

    var channel = ChannelFactory<IService>.CreateChannel(binding, address);

    var result = channel.MethodName(string param1); // Method name and parameters can be changed.
```

Comment: Sorry,but I have program with 3-th year history and I can't rewrite all calls methods base service. I want add calls new service that work with same BusinessModel as base service.